# Django STATIC files does not work in Develop mode

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-templates

Django STATIC files does not work in Develop mode.

I tried in many ways, but I did not succeed.

Could someone tell me where I'm wrong?

Thank you very much for your attention.

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = "/Users/user/Projects/RMA/static/"
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '..', 'static'),
)
```

....

```
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
```

routes

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index')
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

View

```
def index(request):
    return render(request, 'base.html', {'question': 'ads'})
```

template

```
{% load static %}
<link href="{% static 'site/bower_components/select2/dist/css/select2.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: Did you run `python manage.py collectstatic` ?

Comment: Yes, i do .....

Comment: is {% load static %} the very first element of your template ?

Comment: before <!DOCTYPE html>

Comment: Resolved with. STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
    '/Users/.../static/',
].  Thank you people.